# how to alter an index that participates in a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to modify an `index(col1, col2, col3)` to an `index(col1)` without angering a foreign key on `col1`. How do I do it?

My approach was to drop and create the index. But it fails the foreign key while it does it. What is the step to both upgrade and revert the schema?

---

Original:

```
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ...
  UNIQUE KEY `User_sid` (`sid`,`cid`,`uid`),
  ...
  CONSTRAINT `User_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `SolrMap` (`sid`)
```

Objective:

```
  ...,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',       ####ONE LESS COLUMN
  `password_reset_valid_until` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_reset_id` char(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  KEY `User_sid` (`sid`)  ####NEW KEY
  ####WANT NEW FOREIGN KEY
```

And this is what I tried and failed:

```
ALTER TABLE `User` 
        DROP INDEX `User_sid`, 
        ADD INDEX `User_sid` (`sid`) USING BTREE,
        DROP COLUMN `uid`;
```

And this is why it fails:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
121013  8:27:39 Error in foreign key constraint of table friday/User:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "User_ibfk_1" FOREIGN KEY ("sid") REFERENCES "SolrMap" ("sid")
InnoDB: Renaming table `friday`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-6fd_2f12e'> to `friday`.`User` failed!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `User` 
        ADD INDEX `idx_sid` (`sid`) USING BTREE,
        DROP INDEX `User_sid`, 
        DROP COLUMN `uid`;
```

This ensures we still have an index on `sid` **before** we delete the old one.

---

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html :

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, **there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order**. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Disabling Foreign Key Checks or Constraints

```
 SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

 ALTER TABLE `User` 
    DROP INDEX `User_sid`, 
    ...........

 SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Read more http://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/